# Core data find objects containing in list item

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a such model

```
class Group: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var headItems: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var chestItems: NSOrderedSet
}

class Item: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: Int
    @NSManaged var dateCreate: NSDate
}
```

How to write predicate to find all Groups containing in `chestItems` or `headItems` specified item?

This is not working:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Group")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(ANY headItems == %@) or (ANY chestItems == %@)", item,item)
let result = (self.moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Group]) ?? [Group]()
```

UPDATE:
The problem was with updating references in relationship, this code is working

Comment: Do you need to send item again in your predicate? You have two %@ but only one item passed in.

Comment: Sorry, I had them in my 'real' code, and it still not working

Comment: Please provide the full code for how you are setting up and executing the NSFetchRequest with this predicate.

Comment: I've updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use SUBQUERY for this, instead of ANY. Try this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(headItems, $headItem, $headItem.id == %@).@count > 0 OR SUBQUERY(chestItems, $chestItem, $chestItem.id == %@).@count > 0", item.id, item.id )
```

You might also refer to [this cheatsheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) on NSPredicates.

Comment: the same, when I change to  == 0  then it returns all elemtns

Answer (score 0):

I would move away from Core Data if you can, it is not apple's finest piece of work and I find it really horrible to work with and is prone to problems such as yours.

I much prefer DBAccess for persisting data, it's really easy to use and is compatible with both Objective-C and Swift.

http://www.db-access.org/

Comment: This does not address the OP's question.

Comment: Now is a little too late, everything is working expect this